# What is the name of this plastic piece under the Dodge Avenger headlight?

Tags: maintenance, dodge, headlight, replace, parts

This piece fell off when a rock hit the car and now I'm looking to replace it but I don't know what I'm shopping for. Can anyone tell me the name of it?

The car is a 2013 Dodge Avenger.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they are calling it the [Outer Bumper Grill, Driver's Side](http://www.discountbodyparts.com/catalog/feeds/Dodge/Avenger/Replacement/Bumper%20Grille/2013/REPD015506.html?dbpcid=productads&c_aid=16886302222&c2cid=50e4b380-753c-4002-876d-765f75fdca53) .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should take your car to the dealer and have it replaced under warranty, and inspected for further damage. If a rock hit it hard enough to knock it out, then their may be other damage you didn't see, or the part was at least defective, because that should not happen.

It is called a *Lamp Bezel*, and the list price is about $70.